C# System.reflection.emit can't call unmanaged export using Pinvoke
From managed code I can't do a unmanaged call using Pinvoke it is marked as not there and I have labeled it as il. I have only the normal c# libraries and can't install others on the air gapped system.
I created a dll with an umanaged export.
